# Google BigQuery cross join

Tags: google-bigquery, cross-join

I am using cross join to access the data from 2 tables. But with the cross join, I get the error "d.DebugData not found in table "bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails". Any help would be appreciated !!

```
SELECT 
HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, 
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(DebugData,'\\d+') THEN c.Network
  ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\?',' ')
END
as ActualDebugData 
FROM(
 SELECT 
 HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData
 FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigdata:RawDebug.T],TIMESTAMP ('2016-05-15'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15'))
 WHERE Reason = 500  
 ) as d
 CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT Network 
   FROM [bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] 
   WHERE Mcc = substr(d.DebugData,0,3) AND Mnc =   substr(d.DebugData,4,LENGTH(d.Reason - 1)) 
   LIMIT 1 
 ) AS c
```

Tried this but i get this error: " ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name."

```
 %%sql --module Test2
 DEFINE QUERY Test2
 SELECT 
 HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, 
 CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(DebugData,'\\d+') THEN c.Network
  ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\?',' ')
 END AS ActualDebugData 
 FROM (
 SELECT 
   HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, 
   SUBSTR(DebugData,0,3) AS d1, REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(DebugData,3,LENGTH(DebugData)-1),'%[^a-zA-Z0-9, ]%',' ') as d2
   FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigdata:RawDebug.T],TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15'))
   WHERE DebugReason = 500  
   ) AS d
   LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
    Network, Mcc, Mnc
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Mcc, Mnc) AS pos 
    FROM [bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] 
    ) AS c
    ON c.Mcc = INTEGER(d.d1) AND c.Mnc = INTEGER(d.d2)  
    WHERE c.pos = 1
```

I am adding the following structures:

```
 RawDebug:
 HardwareId   DebugReason   DebugData   
 550029358    50013            VER%     
 550029359    50013            RO%      
 550029360    50013            34020?   
 550029361    50013            34021?
```

When the DebugData has characters, then i have case statements matching it, when it has numerals, then i have to take a substring of first 3 characters and match it with Mcc in Carrierdetails and remaining characters and match it with Mnc in Carrierdetails.

With the recent query, it does not consider all the cases. Rather, it takes one specific number and uses tat ActualDebugData for all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, 
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(DebugData,'\\d+') THEN c.Network
    ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\?',' ')
  END AS ActualDebugData 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, 
    SUBSTR(DebugData,0,3) AS d1, SUBSTR(DebugData,4,LENGTH(Reason - 1)) AS d2 
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigdata:RawDebug.T],TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15'))
  WHERE Reason = 500  
) AS d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    Network, Mcc, Mnc
    //,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Mcc, Mnc) AS pos 
  FROM [bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] 
) AS c
ON c.Mcc = d.d1 AND c.Mnc = d.d2  
//WHERE c.pos = 1
```

If `network` is guaranteed to be unique for each entry in d - you can delete commented rows.
Otherwise you should uncomment them

Comment: I have tried the code which i is in the question section. But it throws the error "ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name."

Comment: don't know if you noticed - but this is not what is in my answer! if you need cast those into integers you need to do this not in ON statement but rather withing subselects!!! for example as `INTEGER(SUBSTR(DebugData,0,3)) AS d1`

Comment: This query does not work as expected. It rather takes one specific number and uses it for all the different hardware id's.

Comment: For my requirement, that substring should be calculated only if it is a number. For strings, substring part should not be done. With the present query, it calculates the substring for all rows. That might be one of the reasons it is not working as expected.

Comment: you constantly adding something to your original question. this is not how it works here. either you formulate your full question from the very beginning or you please ask post question every time you add new requirements :o) this is not a forum where we discuss your project or collectivelly work on it - this is question - answer type of communication. new question  - new answer!